# Bootstrap Tabs Messing with Table Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to use bootstrap tab system to display various tables that are formed using `DataTables`. It all works except except the sizing of the `thead` get's messed up when I switch tabs.

[image] [image]

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="overview" role="tabpanel">
      <br/>
      <table id="overview_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>{{ etf1 }}</th>
                <th>{{ etf2 }}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
      </table>
  </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="holdings" role="tabpanel">
        <br/>
        <table id="holdings_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>{{ etf1 }}</th>
                <th>{{ etf2 }}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="performance" role="tabpanel">
        <br/>
        <table id="performance_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>{{ etf1 }}</th>
                <th>{{ etf2 }}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="technicals" role="tabpanel">
        <br/>
        <table id="technicals_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>{{ etf1 }}</th>
                <th>{{ etf2 }}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('/fund_monitor/api/get-comparison/{{ etf1 }}/{{ etf2 }}', function (data) {
           $('#performance_table').DataTable( {
                data:           data['overview'],
                scrollY:        200,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging:         false,
                ordering:       false,
                responsive:     true
            });



            $('#holdings_table').DataTable( {
                data:           data['holdings'],
                scrollY:        200,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging:         false,
                ordering:       false,
                responsive:     true
            });



            $('#technicals_table').DataTable( {
                data:           data['technicals'],
                scrollY:        200,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging:         false,
                ordering:       false,
                responsive:     true
            });
            $('#overview_table').DataTable( {
                data:           data['overview'],
                scrollY:        200,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging:         false,
                ordering:       false,
                responsive:     true
            });
```

So the `thead` is predefined so I think this is the issue. How can I use javascript to resize the `thead cells` after the `DataTable` call? Whats weird is that the first tab works completely fine but the rest do not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table header columns not maintaining width using fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818254/table-header-columns-not-maintaining-width-using-fixed-header)

Answer (score 0):

The tabs can cause some wonky css behaviour.  What I've done on my projects is to reset the css on every tab click.  The example below works on your example, but you may want to be more specific on your css apply than to all tables.

```
$('#TabGroup a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');

            var tableWidth = // determine table/page/div width as integer //;            
            $('table').removeAttr('style').css("width", tableWidth);    

        });
```